# Using \textquotedbl with make4ht

Tags: symbols, font-encodings, make4ht

I help maintain a document which is built, among other ways, with `make4ht --utf8 --lua document.tex` for HTML output.

In order to typeset command line excerpts, the document sometimes uses `\textquotedbl` (i.e.: a plain *ASCII double quote* is needed in the output because it is likely to be copied to a terminal). Yes, I know about `verbatim`, `fancyvrb` and friends, but this is not the subject of the question.

My problem is that on current Debian unstable (`texlive-extra-utils` version 2020.20210202-3), `\textquotedbl` produces the following error when building with `make4ht --utf8 --lua`: `LaTeX Error: Command \textquotedbl unavailable in encoding OT1.`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

ASCII double quote: \textquotedbl.

\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is it a bug in `make4ht` (or `TeX4ht`)? Thanks.

P.S.: my current workaround is to put the following in a .cfg file passed to `make4ht`'s `--config` option:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand { \textquotedbl } { }
  { \HCode { " } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

(...)
```

P.P.S.: I know that `cmr10` has no straight double quote, which is probably part of the explanation of the error message. Still, I believe `\textquotedbl` ought to produce a straight double quote in the HTML output. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, this command seems to be unsupported. This is because it's definition in `tuenc.def` uses some special treatment  and TeX4ht fails to recognize it. It seems that all other commands that are defined here works, except for `\textquotedbl`.

Your work around works, I will add something inspired by it to TeX4ht sources, so it should be fixed in TL soon.

Edit:

It is best to use the updated [latex.4ht](https://gist.github.com/michal-h21/d6744e0768772d213544a93cfd6ebffd) file. It uses `T1` font encoding instead of `OT1` in LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. It should support more characters, like `|`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Great work on `make4ht`, this is very impressive!

Comment: @frougon thank you for your support :) I've added it to TeX4ht sources, so it should be in TL soon.

Comment: Another surprise I had that seems to be related: where the .tex source uses `|`, the HTML output has an U+2014 (EM DASH). Same pattern: the ASCII code for `|` is 0x7C, and the glyph in slot 0x7C of `cmr10` is an em dash, as shown in Appendix A.1 of `texdoc encguide`...

Comment: @frougon yes, this is the similar issue, the `|` character in PDFLaTeX produces dash too.

Comment: In `OT1` encoding, yes, but not in `T1`. :-)

Comment: yes, we probably should use T1 font encoding with LuaLaTeX. I've updated the sources and will post the updated `latex.4ht` file here.

Comment: Many thanks for the updated  `latex.4ht`. Putting it in the document directory before running `make4ht` indeed fixes both problems (`\textquotedbl` and `|`). :-)

Comment: @frougon that's great to hear! I hope this update will get to TL soon, so this updated `latex.4ht` file will be no longer needed.